Are triple fibre products of schemes over different base schemes associative?
Suppose that $(X,f)$ $(Y,g)$ and $(Z,h)$ are $S$ schemes, then it is well known (and easy to prove) that:
$$(X\times_SY)\times_SZ\cong X\times_S(Y\times_SZ)$$
Now suppose that we have another scheme $T$, and $Y$ is both an $S$ and a $T$ scheme with morphisms $g_S$ and $G_T$, and that $Z$ is a $T$ scheme. Then we can endow $X\times_SY$ with the structure of $T$ scheme via $g_T\circ \pi_Y:X\times_SY\rightarrow Y\rightarrow T$, so we can construct $(X\times_SY)\times_TZ$. Similarly, we can give $Y\times_TZ$ the structure of an $S$ scheme, so we can construct $X\times_S(Y\times_TZ)$. Both of these constructions have the naturual structure of an $S$ and a $T$ scheme, so does it follow that
$$(X\times_SY)\times_TZ\cong X\times_S(Y\times_T Z) $$
My instinct is that if this is true it is true for purely universal property reasons, but trying to use it has not panned out for some reason.

This actually holds in any category.

@LukasHeger I agree, hence why I asssumed it would follow from the universal property

By the universal property of the fiber product, in both cases the triple products classify triples of maps
$$
\xi \colon U \to X,
\qquad
\eta \colon U \to Y,
\qquad 
\zeta \colon U \to Z,
$$
such that
$$
f \circ \xi = g_S \circ \eta
\qquad
g_T \circ \eta = h \circ \zeta,
$$
hence they are isomorphic by the Yoneda Lemma.

What is $U$ here?

$U$ is any scheme.
